# Uable to implement redirection in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

Hi all I am facing a problem in node.js ,I want to implement to a redirect function but the function in not implementing I mean this is not redirection to the properpage

```
function(req, res, next) {
        model.setDB(req.db);
               var self = this;

              this.authorize(req,function() {
                if(self.content.userName)
                {
            //req.session.userName = self.content.userName;
        //  req.session.save();
                 var  fullUrl= req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') +'/userChoice';
              res.redirect(fullUrl); 

           }
           else{
            var v = new View(res, 'userlogin');
            v.render({title:"User login"});
            }

        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by not redirecting to the proper page? Are you trying to redirect to the same host (i.e. `http://localhost/blah` to `http://localhost/userChoice`)?

Comment: yes i have solved it...